# mysql condition 'equal' shows condition 'like' attributes

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, sql-like, equality

```
select * from order_info where order_id = 48;
```

The mysql command show above is a very simple sentence, but the result below seems not to meet my expectation, it is more similar to like condition.
[retrieval result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcHDq.png)

I don't know if the type of field may affect the result as the field 'order_id' is varchar type. When I change the condition to " where order_id = '48' ", It meets my expectation.

Can anyone tell me why is this case? Why conditon 'equal' show unexpected outcomes?

I expect the result should be empty as the table does not have the record whose order_id is equal to 48.

Comment: Please share more details. Why did you try to use a integer-based `WHERE` clause on a column that does not contain integers? What would be the expected result?

Comment: This is expected behavior for an integer comparison mysql picks off all the characters before the first alpha character.

Comment: Read about @P.Salmon Comment here, this will clear you what is going on 
[link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this -

```
SELECT CAST('48KKKK' AS INT);
```

You might expect it to fail , it doesn't and the result is 48. Your query is implicitly converting order id before comparison because you are comparing to an integer so the result of your query is correct and it's a gotcha to remember..

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I still wonder why it would consider order id '48'  is equal to '48jkt3.....'  even after implicit conversion from 48 to '48'?